Session Data Lost after Redirection in PHP-FPM
I have set up an Oracle Linux server with Apache httpd and PHP 8.3.12 (running as PHP-FPM). However, the $_SESSION["user"] variable returns null after a page redirection.
The PHP application was previously running successfully on an older CentOS server as well as using XAMPP under Windows desktop environments.
This problem causes my application not able to login users in.
Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue of losing session data after redirection when using PHP-FPM on Oracle Linux?
The session path is set to 0;777; in the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file:
php_value[session.save_path] = "0;777;/var/lib/php/session"

Some things I have checked:

The session save path and permissions are correct
session.save_handler is set to "files"
Restarting PHP-FPM and httpd did not fix the problem.
I deleted all the files in the session.save_path, and upon logging into the application, new session files were generated in the session.save_path.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further would be appreciated.

Redirection from where to where? Did you, for example, go from https://example-a.com/login.php to https://example-b.com/loggedin.php? Can you add the redirection code in your question?

The redirection is from http://example.com/login to http://example.com/ after authentication checking.

Did you check error_log ??

You're implying this is a sessions problem during redirection. Did you check that the problem doesn't exist when you do not redirect? In other words, the session works fine without the redirect? It's always a good idea, if you have two things that could cause a problem, to test them individually.

Does it return to null after any page redirection, or after one specific redirection? Also, is it possible that the page redirects from http to https or vice-versa? Is it only the $_SESSION['user'] variable that returns to null, or every other session variable too?

Side note: Logging in over an unsecured protocol doesn't sound very secure.

I wouldn't start with the assumption that you're losing session data after it's being created, but that the session isn't even being created in the first place. I.e., check session.save_path to see if the files are even there.

@AlexHowansky, I deleted all file in the session.save_path and login the application, some new session files are generated.

And how long do those session files stay there? Maybe they get wiped by an over-eager garbage collector.

@KIKOSoftware, I will install the HTTPS certificate later on.

Does the client successfully get the session cookie? Does the client successfully send the session cookie back to the server post-redirect? Are you perhaps relying on session.auto_start and it's set to false on the new server?

Is there a reverse proxy or similar that maybe clears session cookies on redirect?

The problem was finally resolved by installing the SSL certificate and accessing the website via HTTPS.

It's nice to know what solved the problem, but we still don't know the cause. Is session.cookie_secure set to true? Note that a good answer also explains why your problem happened.
